# vb.net | How to play youtube video or DropBox video in Forms?

Tags: vb.net, forms, video, youtube, playback

I am trying to play a video from my dropbox or from youtube in VB.NET.
Tried it with the media player and with the web browser, but both are much too old.

And doesn't work properly. Do you have any tips?

AxMediaPlayer, WebBrowser doesnt work. It is way to old!

Comment: Maybe the WebBrowser Control doesn't work (if you don't enable its advanced features), but [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) (the new WebBrowser Control) does work

Comment: i try it with webview2..